# Why can't get the old entity value?

Tags: hibernate, playframework

```
Model: User
     id
     username
     role

Controller:update(User u)
  User old = User.findById(u.id);
  if  u.role NOT equals old.role
       .......
```

The Problem is: `User.findById(u.id);` , this code return the user is not as same as PARAM u, NOT the data in database.

How can i get the DATABASE value?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is really confusing.  Do you mean that when you make the call `findbyId(u.id)` that the `old.role` is returning the value found in the `u` parameter and not the value found in the database?

If that's the case, maybe you can try something like this:

```
JPA.em().detach(u);
User old = User.findById(u.id);
if (!u.role.equals(old.role)) {
    ...
}
```

If you actually need to make changes to the User `u` that was detached, you will need to do this:

```
// this will attach the user back to the hibernate session
User merged = JPA.em().merge(u);
// do something like updating the merged user
merged.property = someValue;
merged.save();
```